# Changing font color of selected item by user with select2

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-select2

I've simple select option html:

```
<select name="individual_taxCountry" id="individual_taxCountry" class="select2">
<option value="" selected="selected" class="selected">Select a country</option>
<option value="Afghanistan" >Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Aland Islands" >Aland Islands</option>
<option value="Albania" >Albania</option>
<option value="Algeria" >Algeria</option>
<option value="Zambia" >Zambia</option>
<option value="Zimbabwe" >Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

I am using select2 for this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".select2").select2();
});
```

And I also customized the way the select looks with this css:

```
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single
{
    background-color: #21262d;
    border-color: #21262d;
    border-top-color: #21262d;
    border-right-color-value: #21262d;
    border-bottom-color: #21262d;
    border-left-color-value: #21262d;
    height: 34px;
}
```

It looks the way I want but I would like to change the color to white for the font of the selected item when user does that. How can I accomplish that?

http://jsfiddle.net/bhuffprL/

EDIT: Because not everyone seems to understand my goal - **I want to change to white (fff) color ONLY WHEN user selects his/her own item from the list. The default option I want to be dark.** In other words: 'Select a country' should be dark color as it is and when user selects a country from the list then I want to change font color to white.

Comment: You want to change the color when there's a selected item? If there isn't it should stay as it is?

Comment: @Cassie Kasandr please accept my answer if it it what you want

Comment: here it is i have updated your code check it now: http://jsfiddle.net/bhuffprL/1/

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan correct - I only want to change to white color when user selects his/her own item/option. Default option should be as it is - dark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think some of the solutions using JS though not sure if there's an easier way for that using the select2 plugin.

Easier way I can think of is to create a placeholder instead of having a default option.

**From:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".select2").select2();
});
```

**To:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#individual_taxCountry").select2({
    placeholder: "Select a state*"
  });
});
```

Then on your html, set an empty option value where the placeholder will take place.

**Replacing this:**

```
<option value="" selected="selected" class="selected">Select a country*</option>
```

**To this:**

```
<option></option>
```

Then add those necessary css for the font color

```
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__placeholder {
  color: #444;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
    color: #fff;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ek5yvh2c/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Just add this css to your css code

```
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered{
    color: #fff
}


https://jsfiddle.net/bhuffprL/
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work the way I want. It's change from the beginning to the white (fff) color. I want this to be dark at the beginning and only change to white color when user select his own item/option.