# is there any way to control font for yadcf / select2 choices

Tags: css, fonts, jquery-select2, yadcf

When I create an external filter for a yadcf column, which uses select2 as the selection method, the font in the selections does not follow the .body font specified in the wrapper `<div>`

Is there any way to control this?

See http://codepen.io/louking/pen/rxKeob click in Match field. You can see the font has serif but .body font is Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif.

Note I am using yadcf 0.8.8+ (through commit https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/commit/4b778d7747c5c1cd4f362e6a6154c172f4a88ad3)

html shown below

```
<div class=body>
  <label class="Label">Match:</label><span id="select"></span>

  <table id=tbl class=DataList width=100%>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>col0</th>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>text-obvious</td>
        <td>b0</td>
        <td>c0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>more-text</td>
        <td>b1</td>
        <td>c1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

js shown below

```
options = {
  dom: '<"H"lBpfr>t<"F"i>',
  jQueryUI: true,
  paging: false,
  scrollY: true,
  scrollCollapse: true,
  scrollX: true,
};

var yadcffilters = [{
  column_number: 0,
  filter_container_id: "select",
  column_data_type: "text",
  filter_match_mode: "exact",
  filter_type: "multi_select",
  select_type: 'select2',
  select_type_options: {
    width: '20em',
  },
  filter_reset_button_text: 'all',
}];

var table = $('#tbl').dataTable(options)
  .yadcf(yadcffilters);
```

Comment: Not sure to which elemet exactly you are referring as having serif font, I noticed some with Arial that is being overriden by `user agent` , not sure if that helps you much but you can specify font per element as I did in the [codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbKpZp)

Comment: I'm looking at the font of the select options, which does not appear to be fixed by your css suggestion.

Compare the behavior and font on the pulldown options using select2 in my original example and your update to another example using chosen: http://codepen.io/louking/pen/GoGGbW

I'm want to standardize on select2 because it has a better feature set than chosen.

Comment: take a look at those links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347340/styling-of-select2-dropdown-select-boxes and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060169/changing-font-color-of-selected-item-by-user-with-select2

Comment: I ended up deciding to standardize on selectize. I see yadcf 0.8.9 supports additional select types other than chosen and select2. Is there an example which uses selectize?

Comment: No, sorry, but you can read the docs and ask the author of the PR on github for example https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/pull/212

Comment: Daniel - I am getting bizarre behavior when I try to use this with selectize. Would you entertain a pull request for 'native' yadcf selectize support?

Comment: You asking what I think about getting a PR? sure feel free to send PR :) if you want you can provide an example using selectize with the bizzare....

Comment: actually I got the same bizarre behavior (several selects and reset buttons created, which multiply when I select an option) when I tried to update your code natively to use selectize. I'll try to come up with an example but it's difficult because I'm using ajax to retrieve the select data (yadcf_data_0, etc). Is there an ajax server I can use or do I have to create my own for the bin?

Comment: Or is there a way to simulate an ajax server somehow?

Comment: yes, you can use `"sAjaxSource": "resources/sources/deep.txt",` like I did on showcase http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/ajax_mData_source.html

Comment: am using my own source - I figured it's time for a specific question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35830152/yadcf-custom-select-selectize-bizarre-behavior