# yadcf - custom_select selectize bizarre behavior

Tags: yadcf

Trying to use custom_select with selectize and I am seeing bizarre behavior. The select field gets duplicated as do the reset buttons, and when I pick one of the selects, the fields multiply.

Initializing selectize with

```
  var _selectize;
  yadcf.initSelectPluginCustomTriggers(
    function($filterSelector) {
      _selectize = $filterSelector.selectize({});
    },
    function($filterSelector) {
      _selectize.refreshItems()
    },
    function($filterSelector) {
      _selectize.destroy()
    });
```

Initializing yadcf with

```
var yadcf_options = [{
  'column_number': 0,
  'filter_container_id': "_rrwebapp_filtername",
  'filter_type': "multi_select",
  'select_type': 'custom_select',
  'select_type_options': {
    'width': '30em',
  },
  'filter_reset_button_text': 'all',
}, {
  'column_number': 1,
  'filter_container_id': "_rrwebapp_filterseries",
  'filter_reset_button_text': 'all',
}, ];
```

See http://codepen.io/louking/pen/KzVwwg for details

Compare to when using select2 (which has another problem, but that's for another question) http://codepen.io/louking/pen/RarNwd

Comment: Hi, it will take me some time to investigate that one :|

Comment: Thanks. Understand you are busy, and this one doesn't look easy.

Comment: @LouK I've ran into the same problem... Did you figure it out? Thanks!

Comment: @temuri - no, waiting for Daniel to look at. Using select2 in the meantime.