# Does YADCF multi_select work with custom_select initialized via initSelectPluginCustomTriggers

Tags: datatables, bootstrap-multiselect, yadcf

Having same issue as in thread below but I didn't want to comment on a 2 year old question.

[yadcf - custom_select selectize bizarre behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35830152/yadcf-custom-select-selectize-bizarre-behavior)

I am using yadcf filter type multi select and I am trying to Initialise bootstrap_select as a custom_ select plugin. The custom select is being created fine but I am having the following issues: On page load it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzg1L.png). When you select an option, it duplicates the two list boxes each time like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuALj.png). See code below. Note: I am using the most recent version of yadcf.

```
    var _bootstrapselect;
    yadcf.initSelectPluginCustomTriggers(
        function ($filterSelector) {
            _bootstrapselect = $filterSelector.selectpicker({});
        },
        function ($filterSelector) {
            _bootstrapselect.selectpicker('refresh');
        },
        function ($filterSelector) {
            _bootstrapselect.selectpicker('destroy');
        });
```

Is there any solution to this issue or is it yet to be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this myself. See below for anyone trying to use bootstrap_select with yadcf custom_select.

Initialise initSelectPluginCustomTriggers like below.

```
    var _bootstrapselect;
    yadcf.initSelectPluginCustomTriggers(
        function ($filterSelector) {
            _bootstrapselect = $filterSelector.selectpicker({});
        },
        function ($filterSelector) {
            _bootstrapselect.selectpicker('refresh');
        },
        function ($filterSelector) {
            _bootstrapselect.selectpicker('destroy');
        });
```

And for your column using multi_select, have as below:

```
    yadcf.init(table, [
        {
            column_number: 0,
            filter_container_id: 'external_filter_container_0',
            filter_type: 'multi_select',
            select_type: 'custom_select',
            style_class: 'selectpicker',
            filter_default_label: 'Filter Value',
            filter_reset_button_text: false,
        }
    ]);
```

I was just missing the style class 'selectpicker' in column 0. Silly.

See [here](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/) for more bootstrap-select methods that can be used in the initSelectPluginCustomTriggers for init, refresh and destroy functions.